# Android Audio recording sample sounds weird

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I wrote code to record audio from my phone in PCM16bit Raw format but when I play it back the output sounds weird. What could be wrong.

My code segments are as below

```
short[] audioBuffer = new short[bufferSize / 2];

AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            bufferSize);
```

Sample rate is at 44100 .

```
        int numberOfShort1 = record.read(audioData,0,audioData.length);
        shortsRead += numberOfShort;
        readtimes++;


            try {
                os.write(audioData, 0, audioData.length);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error saving recording ", e);
                //runonce=2;
                return;
            }
```

Could someone tell me whats wrong with my code?I am able to play other raw audios well.

This is how it sounds [Link to audio](https://youtu.be/Je1yZt-kwv4)
My voice sounds like some weird alien growl.

Comment: What is `numberOfShort`? How is 'audioData' related to `audioBuffer`? Your code fragments are too short to say something useful

Comment: Solved. But now I am trying to store the audio buffer as .wav file and it sound speeded up like by atleast 4 times.

Comment: Maybe you write four times less data to the file than necessary? Or the sample rate you write to the file is four times too high?

Comment: solved. Was a problem with last byte.